# How do I install discord.js on Visual Studio Code?

Tags: npm, terminal, discord, discord.js

I tried installing discord.js on my terminal in Visual Studio Code. But whenever I run `npm init -y` or `npm install discord.js`, I get an error message that says this every time:

> npm : The term 'npm' is not recognized as the name of a  cmdlet,
> function, script file, or operable program. Check    the spelling of
> the name, or if a path was included,         verify that the path is
> correct and try again. At line:1 char:1
>
> - npm
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (npm:String)  
>     [], CommandNotFoundException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>   ```

How do I fix this and install discord.js?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you dont have Node.js installed on your machine.
You can download it [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/).

When installed, just use `npm i discord.js`.